# Dynamic Widgets/UI Elements using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, dynamic, widget

I'm working on a GUI web application which basically consists of 3 tab containers that dynamically load different tabs based on server messaging (I'm using cometd). This is a chess gaming app, so, for example, when the server brings in a Game message, I need to create a game board and add it to one of the tab containers.

I figure I can use custom directives with some templating to neatly define the behavior of these different UI components but, is there a way to programmatically add them to the template? Like, for example, adding a chessboard HTML tag and then makeing Angular compile it and linking to the directive at runtime?

Is there any other good solution to this aproach? I'm also using Grids that update with lots of rows for games and user lists, other UI components like accordions, dialogs, so I'm also looking for an Angular based UI framework.

Thanks!

Edited: Here's the code sample HTML and Js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Angular Test App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>AngularJS Test</h1>

    <style type="text/css">
        .section-wrapper { 
            width: 500px; 
            height: 400px; 
            border: 1px solid #eee;}

        .nav-tabs li {
            position: relative;
        }
        .nav-tabs li .close-tab {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 15px;
            cursor: default;
            padding: 1px 4px;
        }
        .nav-tabs li .close-tab:hover {
            color: #fff;
            background: red;
        }
        .nav-tabs li .detach-tab {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            font-family: monospace;
            font-size: 15px;
            cursor: default;
            padding: 1px 4px;
        }
        .nav-tabs li .detach-tab:hover {
            color: #fff;
            background: #666;
        }

    </style>

    <section ng-controller="LiveChessCtrl">
        <div class="section-wrapper">

            <tabset>
                <tab ng-repeat="game in (chessGames | filter:!detached)">
                    <tab-heading>
                        {{ game.players.join(' vs ') }}
                        <span class="detach-tab" ng-click="detachGame(game.gameId)">D</span>
                        <span class="close-tab" ng-click="endGame(game.gameId)">X</span>
                    </tab-heading>
                    <div id="{{ game.gameId }}"><chess-board-controller game-id="{{ game.gameId }}"></chess-board-controller></div>
                </tab>
            </tabset>

        </div>
    </section>

    <button onclick="javascript:simulateIncomingCometdMessage()">Simulate a New Game message coming from cometd server</button>

    <script src="js/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/testApp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the JS file demonstrating what I'm trying to do:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('LiveChessCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        var lastGameIndex = 1;
        $scope.chessGames = {};

        $scope.newGame = function (opts) {
            opts = opts || {};

            var chessGame = {
                gameId: 'chessboard_' + lastGameIndex,
                players: opts.players,
                detached: false
            };

            $scope.chessGames[chessGame.gameId] = chessGame;
            lastGameIndex++;
        };

        $scope.endGame = function (gameId) {
            delete $scope.chessGames[gameId];
        };

        $scope.detachGame = function (gameId) {
            $scope.chessGames[gameId].detached = true;

            // TODO: Add a modal dialog and inject the ChessBoard custom directive inside
        };

        $scope.newGame({
            players: ['Dummy', 'Game'],
            boardSize: 'auto',
            colorScheme: 'metal',
            chessBoardBorder: false
        });
}]);

app.directive('chessBoardController', function($compile) {
    return {
        template: '<div id="chessboard_[[ gameId ]]></div>',
        restrict: "E"
    }
});

// Instead of writing a complete cometd implementation, 
// let's just say we handle incoming messages here:
var dummyGameMessages = [ 
    {
        players: ['John', 'Paul'],
        boardSize: 'auto',
        colorScheme: 'metal',
        chessBoardBorder: false
    },
    {
        players: ['Bill', 'Lucy'],
        boardSize: 'auto',
        colorScheme: 'graffiti',
        chessBoardBorder: false
    },
    {
        players: ['Joe', 'Danny'],
        boardSize: 'auto',
        colorScheme: 'graffiti',
        chessBoardBorder: false
    }
];
var curGameMsg = 0;

var simulateIncomingCometdMessage = function() {
    var Game = dummyGameMessages[curGameMsg++];

    if (curGameMsg > 2)
        curGameMsg = 0;
    // TODO: Reference LiveChessCtrl $scope to programatically call newGame with the game information
    //   more over, I have the issue that on certain occations, there are different stuff that I want included
    //   in the same TabContainer. We now know that every thing I add to this container is a chess-board-game
    //   directive, but what about if I want to add a grid with the list of games, for example?
}
```

Now in this sample we're adding chess-board-controllers to the tab container, but ideally, we should identify incomming messages from cometd and be able to add any type of controller, so the HTML markup used there and the declarative approach doesn't seem to be working, unless I'm not correctly seeing the picture here.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: If you don't show your code nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: sorry, the old app uses dojo and it's 30K+ lines of code. I haven't yet started on a new app, should I create a concept sample and post it here?

Comment: Yeah, maybe you should do so. :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'll work on that and get back to you. Should I comment right here or below where it says "Answer Your Question" where it will be more visible?

Comment: I edited my message and added code samples. Thanks for any help you might provide!